# Como selecionar dados no R?

Tags: r

Tenho um banco de dados com 1441 linhas. Preciso agrupá-los em grupos de 30, e extrair médias de cada um desses subgrupos. Há algum comando que me permita fazer tudo isso automaticamente? "a cada 30 linhas, criar uma nova coluna e calcular a média". Estou separando os dados manualmente, o que vai me tomar tempo. Estou fazendo assim:

```
primeiro = pott [1:30,c('GPP')]
segundo = pott [31:60,c('GPP')]
```

E assim sucessivamente, até 1441. Não vejo essa forma como muito prática! :s

Desde já agradeço quem puder me ajudar

Answer (score 5):

De fato, não é boa ideia fazer isso à mão, muito menos ter tantos objetos no `globalenv`. O melhor é criar essas sub `data.frames` numa lista, com, por exemplo, `split`.

```
set.seed(4577)  # porque vou usar 'rnorm' para criar a data.frame

n <- 1441
pott <- data.frame(GPP = rnorm(n))

fact <- rep(1:(1 + n %/% 30), each = 30)[seq_len(n)]

lista_pott <- split(pott, fact)
```

Agora, para fazer cálculos usamos as funções `*apply`.

```
medias <- sapply(lista_pott, function(x) mean(x$GPP))
```

Answer (score 4):

Usando a base de dados de exemplo do Rui, outra alternativa é:

```
tapply(pott$GPP, gl(nrow(pott)/30, 30), mean)
```

Explicando: o comando  `gl(nrow(pott)/30, 30)` cria fatores de tamanho 30 para a sua base de dados. E o `tapply` faz o `split` com `sapply` ao mesmo tempo, aplicando a função `mean` ao vetor `pott$GPP` para cada fator de 30 observações.